# When do extra lives spawn in Pac-Man Championship Edition 2?

Tags: pac-man-championship-edition-2

What causes an extra life to spawn on the board in Pac-Man Championship Edition 2? They occasionally appear as little pac-man icons in the maze. I'm rarely able to collect them because they always seem to spawn right as I'm about to jump to another board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extra life will spawn every 1,000,000 points in Single Train, Regular, or Practice mode. They do not spawn in Extreme mode.

You earn a lot of points when eating ghost chains, so keep an eye on your score before leaving the board.